# django-filter: Style choicefiled

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have created django-filter in order to perform column filtering on django-table2, BUT I'm still unable to style the generated drop down list in order to match the overall page style

-I am using Bootsrap3

Kindly, post any suggestion to solve this issue, Or should I do the column filtering using regular django forms

Here is my filter class form filter.py

```
Pi_FILTER_CHOICES= (('', 'Select PI#'),(1,"PI1"),(2,"PI2"),(3,"PI3"),)
class PI_NameFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    pi_name = filters.ChoiceFilter( label = "PI Name", choices=Pi_FILTER_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        modle = SamplesLinkage
```

Here is the filter on my template

```
{% block filter %}
<form action="" method="get">
      <label for="id_pi_name">Search by PI:  </label>
      {{ filter.form.pi_name }}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Go Find
      </button>

 </form>
 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You (or at least anyone who will still face this issue in the future) will have to render form fields manually using this documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}">Email subject:</label>
    {{ form.subject }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.message.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.message.id_for_label }}">Your message:</label>
    {{ form.message }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.sender.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.sender.id_for_label }}">Your email address:</label>
    {{ form.sender }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.cc_myself.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.cc_myself.id_for_label }}">CC yourself?</label>
    {{ form.cc_myself }}
</div>
```